# Installed "vanilla" TeX Live on Debian but apt still tries to install "texlive-" packages

Tags: linux, debian, apt, package-management, latex

I had `TeX Live 2022` installed and upgraded to `TeX Live 2023`. Below is the list of steps that I followed, courtesy of [tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu):

1. Remove old installation

```
sudo apt-get purge texlive*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/*
sudo rm -rf ~/.texlive*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/texmf
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/texmf
sudo rm -rf /etc/texmf
sudo apt-get remove tex-common --purge
find -L /usr/local/bin/ -lname /usr/local/texlive/*/bin/* | xargs -r rm
sudo rm -rf /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf
sudo fc-cache
```

2. Dependencies

```
sudo apt install wget perl-tk
```

3. Download script

```
wget https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
tar -xf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
cd install-tl- #(Press TAB to autocomplete)
```

4. Run script

```
sudo ./install-tl
```

5. Set environment variables

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/man
export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/info
```

6. Verify install

```
which tex
```

7. Trick package

```
sudo apt install equivs --no-install-recommends freeglut3
mkdir -p /tmp/tl-equivs && cd /tmp/tl-equivs
equivs-control texlive-local
```

8. Edit texlive-local

```
wget -O texlive-local https://tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2022-ex.txt
```

In this step I used [the example file from 2022](https://www.tug.org/texlive/files/debian-equivs-2022-ex.txt) and changed the years to 2023. So it looked like this:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 4.1.4

Package: texlive-local
Version: 2023.99999999-1
Maintainer: you <you@yourdomain.example.org>
Provides: chktex, biblatex, biblatex-dw, cm-super, cm-super-minimal, context, 
 dvidvi, dvipng, feynmf, fragmaster, jadetex, lacheck, latex-beamer, 
 latex-cjk-all, latex-cjk-chinese, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp, 
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp, 
 latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp, latex-cjk-common, latex-cjk-japanese, 
 latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab, latex-cjk-korean, latex-cjk-thai, latexdiff, 
 latexmk, latex-sanskrit, latex-xcolor, lcdf-typetools, lmodern, luatex, 
 musixtex, passivetex, pgf, preview-latex-style, prosper, ps2eps, psutils, 
 purifyeps, t1utils, tex4ht, tex4ht-common, tex-gyre, texlive, texlive-base, 
 texlive-bibtex-extra, texlive-binaries, texlive-common, texlive-extra-utils,
 texlive-fonts-extra, texlive-fonts-extra-doc, texlive-fonts-recommended,
 texlive-fonts-recommended-doc, texlive-font-utils, texlive-formats-extra,
 texlive-games, texlive-generic-extra, texlive-generic-recommended,
 texlive-humanities, texlive-humanities-doc, texlive-lang-african,
 texlive-lang-all, texlive-lang-arabic, texlive-lang-cjk, texlive-lang-cyrillic,
 texlive-lang-czechslovak, texlive-lang-english, texlive-lang-european,
 texlive-lang-japanese, texlive-lang-chinese, texlive-lang-korean,
 texlive-lang-french, texlive-lang-german, texlive-lang-greek, 
 texlive-lang-indic, texlive-lang-italian, texlive-lang-other, 
 texlive-lang-polish, texlive-lang-portuguese, texlive-lang-spanish,
 texlive-latex-base, texlive-latex-base-doc, texlive-latex-extra, 
 texlive-latex-extra-doc, texlive-latex-recommended, 
 texlive-latex-recommended-doc, texlive-luatex, texlive-math-extra, 
 texlive-metapost, texlive-metapost-doc, texlive-music,
 texlive-omega, texlive-pictures, texlive-pictures-doc, texlive-plain-extra,
 texlive-plain-generic,
 texlive-pstricks, texlive-pstricks-doc, texlive-publishers,
 texlive-publishers-doc, texlive-science, texlive-science-doc, texlive-xetex,
 thailatex, tipa, tipa-doc, xindy, xindy-rules, xmltex, asymptote, texinfo
Depends: freeglut3
Architecture: all
Description: My local installation of TeX Live 2023.
 A full "vanilla" TeX Live 2023
 http://tug.org/texlive/debian#vanilla
```

9. Build and install package

```
equivs-build texlive-local
sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_ #(TAB)
sudo apt install -f
```

10. Update TeXLive

```
sudo tlmgr update --all
sudo tlmgr --gui
```

Later I tried `SageTex` on `TexWorks` but when compiling I got error `sagetex.sty not found`. I thought it came with Tex Live. I headed to my terminal and did `sudo apt install sagetex`. To my surprise apt tried to install `texlive-` prefixed packages.

```
sudo apt install sagetex

The following NEW packages will be installed:

dvisvgm libptexenc1 libteckit0 libtexlua53 libtexluajit2 lmodern preview-latex-style ps2eps python3-sagetex tex-gyre texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-font-utils texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended texlive-pictures texlive-plain-generic tipa
```

Those packages were explicitly mentioned in the above file so I was confused why apt was still trying to get them. Will ignoring this and installing `SageTeX` break my setup? Did I mess up and should reinstall `TeX Live 2023`? What is the right way to get `SageTeX` to work in this situation? Compiling ordinary `LaTeX` files with `pdfLaTeX` works fine in `TeXWorks`.

This is my `SageTex` compilation script in `TexWorks`:

```
#!/bin/sh
pdflatex "${1}.tex"
sage "${1}.sagetex.sage"
pdflatex "${1}.tex"
```